# Foundation Gem Error (permission denied rbenv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Everything going fine with setting up Foundation for Sass except I ran into this error? Can anyone shed some light on it?

I'm on OSX 10.10, git version 2.3.5, ruby 2.1.5p273, node v0.12.2 and Bower 1.4.1.

```
gem install foundation 

My-MacBook-Pro:Desktop me$ gem install foundation
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)

Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-1.0.4/.gitignore
```

Cheers, Brock

Comment: Did you try `rbenv rehash`?

Comment: Can you install any other gem with `gem install` or it's only specific to Foundation?

Comment: I'm not sure what rbenv rehash does B Seven, but I tried it and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: p4sh4 - not sure how to test that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just try to install any other gem, like `gem install thor`, does it give the same error? In any case, it seems that your rbenv permissions are out of order. How did you install `rbenv`, was it from another user on the same machine by any chance?

Comment: Installed Thor fine. Did a Sudo install as per the Zurb Foundation doc and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help. :)